# What is the best way to add big amount of html elements using innerHTML idea?

Tags: javascript, ajax, innerhtml

Not on Chrome, but on Firefox the browser just get freeze every time I make an ajax request.

Here's the deal...

The ajax request receive a huge html, where the length is more than 75,000.

```
<div> ... <table> ... etc ... </table> ... </div>
```

So I start to use replace to get something better:

```
var html = data.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '').replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ')
```

Than I got 55,000 that is not enough.

So I've been searching but until now I got nothing that can help.

Here's what I tried:

1.

```
asyncInnerHTML(html, function(fragment){
     $(tab).get(0).appendChild(fragment); // myTarget should be an element node.
});
```

2.

```
var node = document.createTextNode(html);
$(tab).get(0).innerHTML = node;
```

3.

```
$(tab).get(0).innerHTML = html;
```

4.

```
$(tab).append(html);
```

5.

```
$(tab).html(html);
```

The only thing that was fast what the second one, where the javascript add the nodeContent, of course that was not what I want, because I need the HTML rendered and not the html in text/string form.

I hope that someone could help me.

Anyway, thanks.

Comment: If the browser freezes when adding HTML, then the logical question is what is in the HTML that is causing it to freeze?  75k of HTML is nothing for a web page - any browser can certainly handle that sized HTML.  So, it likely depends upon the specific HTML.  Something in there is causing a problem for Firefox.  Also, when you say freeze, what do you mean?

Comment: @jfriend00, see the html http://codepen.io/rochapablo/pen/ogBbom. When I say that freeze, means that Windows threat the browser stop not answering.

Comment: The Firefox performance tool should give you insight into what is slow about the HTML you are trying to render.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Performance

Comment: @JoshuaD.Boyd I just did, but I got nothing relevant.

Comment: If I am interpreting the firefox performance tool's output correctly, that pause is just how long firefox takes to render that HTML.  If feasible, try statically sizing the table and using the table-layout: fixed; style.

Comment: Interesting that I don't see an issue in Firefox using this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/oq8j90ux/.  I don't think it's the size of the HTML causing the problem, but I'm not sure yet what it is.  You could parse out the HTML for the table rows and add each row separately to prevent one long operation.

Comment: @jfriend00, I've just tried your link but I got the same freeze problem. So I start to think why at your browser works but not my. Then I start to look at the Firefox plugins where I have "bank account", Selenium (lot of them) and Skype. I disable all these and tried again. And works pretty well, after that I went to my application and tried the 3o example and works too. So for now, I think that the problem was one of those plugins.

Comment: @jfriend00, it's the Skype Click to Call plugin that shit the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Skype Toolbar for Firefox is an extension that detects phone numbers in web pages, and re-renders them as a clickable button that can be used to dial the number using the Skype desktop application.

So, when the HTML is rendered, the skype extension try to find shit at my code making the browser stop work for a moment.

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a piece of code that parses out the rows from your table HTML and then adds them one at a time to give the browser more time to breathe while parsing your HTML.  This parsing logic is specific to your HTML and makes some assumptions about that HTML:

```
function addLargeHTML(parent, h) {
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    var pieces = extractRows(html);
    d.innerHTML = pieces.core;
    var tbody = $(d).find("tbody");
    $(parent).append(d);
    var cntr = 0;
    function next() {
        if (cntr < pieces.rows.length) {
            tbody.append(pieces.rows[cntr]);
            ++cntr;
            setTimeout(next, 1);
        }
    }
    next();
}

function extractRows(h) {
    var body;
    var h = h.replace(/<tbody>(.*?)<\/tbody>/, function(match, p1) {
        body = p1;
        return "<tbody></tbody>";
    });
    var rows = body.match(/<tr.*?<\/tr>/g);
    return {core: h, rows: rows};
}
```

You can see it working in this jsFiddle (select the "Add Row by Row" button): http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/z7jn4p12/.

Since I could not reproduce your original problem in Firefox, I can't really say whether this would fix what you saw or not.  But, it does break the HTML up into smaller pieces so if that was really the problem, this should help.